# RemoteViews setViewVisibility on Android Widget

Tags: java, android, widget, visibility, remoteview

In my AppWidgetProvider, I do following:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(NEXTPAGE_ACTION)) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(ctx);
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.page1, View.GONE);
        rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.page2, View.VISIBLE);
    final int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
    }
}
```

Although I'm updating the layout via updateAppWidget, the change is not really reflected on the UI. What could be possibly going wrong? Thanks much!

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried using INVISIBLE and not GONE? Gone will remove the view as if it were never there. And invisible will hold the view's place in the layout, but make it invisible.

```
 rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.page1, View. INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Tried both but none is working. Are you sure INVISIBLE works?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with widget app. I detect **appWidgetId** wrong if you get like that. When the first time update UI, you must track **appWidgetId** to a static variable. And then, we can use that variable as common **appWidgetId** for update UI.

Or you can try code below in **onReceiver** function:

`final ComponentName provider = new ComponentName(context, this.getClass());
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(provider, views);`

which views is **RemoteViews**.

Thanks, sorry about my English.